# How to update my app with different packagename?

Tags: android, package-name, app-update

I had an app with a certain packagename,but now I have to change the packagename of the same app.So,how could I do easily and if the users can update the app's version turning to another packagename?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To change the package name you need to change the   `applicationId` in your `build.gradle` file. 
The users cannot upgrade you app to different package name. different package name will be treated as different application.

Answer (score 1):

Just right follow this stap

right click on your project --> Android Tools --> Rename Application Package.

after that you got a popup dialog with your current package name now put your new package name...

Comment: Are there two apps in users's cellphone or just the latest one?

Comment: How to just retain the latest one as the two apps are just different of packagename not the contents.

Answer (score 0):

When doing an update for an app, it should have the same package name, and should always be signed with the original signing certificate used when the app was first published.

If you upload your update with a different package name, the play store will treat it as two separate apps, I'm not sure whether or not it will allow the same application name, as viewing in app listings, to be the same, I don't believe it does so you would probably get an error anyway stating that an app with that name already exists.

If the actual application name is also different, then the play store will treat it as two different apps.

If you change your package name to be the same as the original package name, you can update the app as long as you use the same signing certificate as the original app.